# Python: How to validate and append non-existing row in a dataset/dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, append

How can we append a non-existing row/value in a dataset? I have here a sample table with list of names and the objective is to validate first the name if this doesn't exist and append it to the dataset.

Please see code below for reference:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Name': ['Nik', 'Kate', 'Evan', 'Kyra'],
    'Age': [31, 30, 40, 33],
    'Location': ['Toronto', 'London', 'Kingston', 'Hamilton']
})

df = df.append({'Name':'Jane', 'Age':25, 'Location':'Madrid'}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the condition before insering in the dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Name': ['Nik', 'Kate', 'Evan', 'Kyra'],
    'Age': [31, 30, 40, 33],
    'Location': ['Toronto', 'London', 'Kingston', 'Hamilton']
})

if 'Jane' not in df.Name.values:
    df = df.append({'Name':'Jane', 'Age':25, 'Location':'Madrid'}, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ghassen I did try but it still appends

Comment: Note that `append` is getting deprecated, better use `loc` or `concat`. Another option is to set Name as index.

Comment: it's normal for it to append because 'Jane' is not in the initial dataframe, if you want to add only the existant name change the condition to if 'Jane' in df.Name

Comment: Yes, you need to use `if 'Jane' not in df.Name.values`, else you match the indices.

Comment: Thank you @GhassenSultana and @mozway `if 'Jane' not in df.Name.values` works! I let you know if I have follow-up question